# Read model with data from multiple aggregate roots (different contexts)

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm curious to how to join data from multiple aggregate roots in an read model for an event sourced aggregate root. Can try to take a simple example:

If I have an aggregate root called Cart which supports following events in it's event stream (properties in parentheses - keep in mind this is an simple example):

```
AddProductToCart(cartId: Int, productId: Int)
RemoveProductFromCart(cartId: Int, productId: Int)
AddUserLicenseToProduct(cartId: Int, productId: Int, userId: Int)
RemoveUserLicenseFromProduct(cartId: Int, productId: Int, userId: Int)
EmptyCart(cartId: Int)
```

It's ok when projecting read models with data coming from this event stream. I can for example project a cart object which looks something like this:

```
Cart(cartId: Int, products: List[Product])

Product(productId: Int, userLicenses: List[UserLicense])
UserLicense(userId: Int)
```

But how does one join data from another aggregate root in another context into this cart projection. For example if I wanted to extend the read model with data from the Product aggregate root which lives in another context. Let's say I would like to extend it with productName and productType.

Take into consideration we are working in an distributed system, where Product and Cart would be live in different services/applications.

I suppose one solution would be to include the data in the commands and events. But that doesn't seem to scale very well if one would have larger read models with data from multiple aggregate roots. Also one has to be able to nuke and rebuild the read model.

I suppose another solution would be to duplicate data from other aggregate roots into the storage of other applications/services/contexts. For example duplicate the productName and productType data into storage owned be the Cart application, but not have it be a part of the Cart event stream. The Cart application would then have to listen to events (e.g. ProductCreated, ProductNameChanged) to keep data updated. I guess this might be a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Each bounded context should be loosely coupled. We had a similar issue with two of our contexts. The solution that we found was to use workflows by creating all the communication between contexts in those files. In which we could synchronize the required schemas by subscribing to an event handler. As we used Elixir, the library that we have been used is Commanded, which have its own Event Bus.

But in a distributed systems you can use Apache Kafka. At the end of the day, I think that the easier solution should keep your schemas the cleanest possible (it also going to help you to respect the GDPR compliance) and to manage all your communication through a separate layer by an event handler.

To see this solution in a "real-life" way, I can recommend you a great example repository built with Elixir.

https://leanpub.com/buildingconduit/read

Answer (score 0):

This question also comes up with event-driven architectures and not only event-sourcing.  I reckon that you've covered most options in terms of capturing the relevant data from the producer of the event.

Another option would be that an event contain as little data as possible from the related bounded context.  At a minimum that would be an identifier.  However, in most cases some of the data should be denormalized to make sense.  For instance, having the product description denormalized into the `Cart` and eventual `Order` would be helpful especially when someone changes the description after I have made my choice.  The description may change from `Blue pen` to `Red pen` which would drastically alter what I intended to purchase.  In this case the `Product` in your `Shopping` BC *may* be represented by a value object that contains the `Id` along with the `Description`.

If you now would like to augment the read-only data we are left only with the option of retrieving it from the source BC.  This can be done in the read-model using some API (Rest/ACL) and then the data saved.  To make it more fault tolerant one may opt for a messaging/service bus infrastructure to handle the retrieval of the additional data and updating of the relevant read-model record.